# Workflow formula -- Simple or double quote?

Tags: workflow, formula

I've a collegue who is asking me what difference one has to the other,
I have to admit I don't have an exact answer..

What is best practise in this case ?

Which one do you choose, and why ?

Comment: Both single or double quote works, It is preferable to use double quotes for String type values. In Apex, it will be single quotes

Comment: I use single quotes. I do this because have different developers helping me with projects and single quotes is used in Java/Apex so it is easier to keep track of. I also use != in formulas and && instead of nested and() for the same reasons.